# How to create URL of 3 level deep category in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating one project in Laravel, in which there are 3 levels of deep category structure.

for example: clothes -> men -> t-shirts

So I want URL for this category structure like clothes/men/t-shirts/

database structure :

```
id name     parent
1  clothes  0
2  men      1
3  t-shirts 2
```

I am not able to create the URL of this category structure.

Route for category page:

```
Route::get('/categories/{slug?}/{sub?}', 'FrontController@showCategories')
```

I am new to Laravel, so I don't know any other way.

```
public function showCategories($slug = '', $sub = ''){

        $link = '';

        if(empty($slug)){
            $parent = 0;
        }else{

            $category = Category::first()->where('slug', $slug)->pluck('id');
            
            $parent = $category[0];
            
            if(!empty($sub)){

                $category = Category::first()->where('slug', $sub)->pluck('id');
            
                $parent = $category[0];
            }
        
        }

        $categories = Category::all()->where('parent', $parent);

        return view('front.categories', compact('categories'));
    }
```

Laravel version 6.2

Comment: Would you show your route code?

Comment: You're gonna need some recursion, from the top-level down to the Nth child. This is not something we're going to be able to answer without seeing how you've setup your model, including self-referencing relationships (parent, child) and the logic you're using to get the lowest-level Category.

Comment: @STA I have added the route for the category.

Comment: Show the showCategories method code defined in FrontController.

Comment: @TimLewis I have one table for category_product relationship. where I am storing category id and product id. and there is nothing in the category model except for the function products with `belongsToMany`

Comment: Products doesn't matter here (yet); you've got nested Categories, which is a self-referencing recursive relationship... That's a complicated data structure, and I don't know if you've done the proper legwork to have that functioning. Does your `Category` model have a function for `parent()` and `children()`? etc etc.

Comment: @MdShahbazAhmad I have added the `showCategories` method in the question.

Comment: @TimLewis No :P what that functions will do? I mean can you give an example?

Comment: Like I said, it's complicated... Basically, a `Category` can `belongsTo` one `Category` (via the `parent()` relationship), while it can simultaneously  `hasMany` other `Category` records (via the `children()` relationship). This kind of relationship allows for infinite levels of nesting, and recursive logic to go from top-level (parent) to bottom-level (child) rows, but is the proper approach to nesting. I can't help with this question if you don't know how to create this kind of data structure though...

Comment: @AkshayRathod I have added my answer. please check if it as per your requirement or not.

Answer (score 0):

**1st variant:** I think you need to create a root part for your url. For example `/catalog/` then your route will be something like this:

`Route::get('/catalog/', 'GoodsController@index');`

After, where is two ways to make your routes:

1. (In my opinion this is a bad way) Add a optional parameters for every depth category:

`Route::get('/catalog/{category?}/{sub_category?}/{sub_sub_category?}..etc', 'CatalogController@index');`

And work with it in your controller.

2. Do you optional parameter like categories path:

`Route::get('/catalog/{categories_path?}', 'CatalogController@index');`

Then, in your controller you can parse this path by `explode` function, like this:

```
// CatalogController.php
    public function index(string $categories_path)
    {
        $categories = explode('/', $categories_path);
        if (!is_array($categories)) {
            $goods = Goods::all(); //if no category get
            return view('catalog', compact('goods')); //return all goods
        }
        $activeCategory = array_pop($categories); //get the last category from path
        // do anything with active category
        // $category = Category::whereSlug($activeCategory)->first(); // or something else
    }
```

> **NOTE:** Pay attention `array_pop` changes you array. More info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php

**2nd variant:** if you don't want have the `catalog` root url part, you need to make it manually via regular expression like this:

`Route::get('/{category}/{categories_path?}', 'GoodsController@index')->where('category', '[clothes|shoes|bags]+');`

Links:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

If I don't understand your question right, please, let me know, I change my answer.

Comment: I will need the URL for `Route::get('/catalog/{category?}/{sub_category?}/{sub_sub_category?}..etc', 'CatalogController@index');` so I need that URL everything else I will handle. how I will create links for this route. for example /clothes/ route will show men and women subcategory so the link for that will be /clothes/men and /clothes/women and link that for Nth child.

Comment: So, I think you need look at this package: https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Answer (score 0):

As far I have understand, you want to know how to create a url link for these categories in the view page.

Give your route a name

```
Route::get('/catalog/{category?}/{sub_category?}/{sub_sub_category?}', 'FrontController@showCategories')->name('categories.slug.sub');
```

And in the view page assuming (view.blade.php)

```
<a href="{{ route('categories.slug.sub') }}"> All Catergories </a>
<a href="{{ route('categories.slug.sub', ["category"=>"clothes"]) }}"> Clothes </a>
<a href="{{ route('categories.slug.sub', ["category"=>"clothes", "sub_category"=>"men"]) }}">Men</a>
<a href="{{ route('categories.slug.sub', ["category"=>"clothes", "sub_category"=>"men", "sub_sub_category"=>"t-shirt"]) }}"> T-shirt </a>
```